# com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector: -> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Not scanning on Marshmallow

Tags: android, zxing

Android Studio 3.6

Android 6.0

app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    //viewBinding.enabled = true
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 2
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta05'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

in my activity

```
class QRScanActivity : RootActivity() {
    private lateinit var dataBinding: QrScanActivityBinding
    private val REQUEST_PERMISSION = "REQUEST_PERMISSION"
    private val REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 1
private lateinit var beepManager: BeepManager

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView<QrScanActivityBinding>(this, R.layout.qr_scan_activity)
        dataBinding.setHandler(this)
        init()
    }

 private fun initLogic() {
        dataBinding.decoratedBarcodeView.decodeContinuous(object : BarcodeCallback {
            override fun barcodeResult(result: BarcodeResult?) {
                beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
                finish();
            }

            override fun possibleResultPoints(resultPoints: MutableList<ResultPoint>?) {

            }
        })
}
```

in xml layout:

```
<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/decoratedBarcodeView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/qrButtonScan"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolBarContainer" />
```

Success work on **Android 9.0**. Nice.

But when I start on **Android 6.0** I get error:

```
10-28 16:28:35.145 D/com.myproject.ui.actviity.QRScanActivity( 2405): possibleResultPoints:
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405): FATAL EXCEPTION: DecoderThread
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405): Process: com.myproject.debug, PID: 2405
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method sort(Ljava/util/Comparator;)V in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.selectBestPatterns(FinderPatternFinder.java:616)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternFinder.find(FinderPatternFinder.java:164)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.Detector.detect(Detector.java:81)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader.decode(QRCodeReader.java:77)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.decodeInternal(MultiFormatReader.java:173)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.decodeWithState(MultiFormatReader.java:87)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:75)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:49)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoderThread.decode(DecoderThread.java:146)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoderThread.access$000(DecoderThread.java:22)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoderThread$1.handleMessage(DecoderThread.java:38)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-28 16:28:35.484 E/AndroidRuntime( 2405):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-28 16:28:35.486 W/ActivityManager(  780):   Force finishing activity com.myproject.debug/com.myproject.ui.actviity.QRScanActivity
10-28 16:28:35.486 E/CrashlyticsCore( 2405): Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@451f81a
10-28 16:28:35.487 E/CrashlyticsCore( 2405): Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@e9abf4b
10-28 16:28:35.488 E/CrashlyticsCore( 2405): Error occurred sending report com.crashlytics.android.core.SessionReport@d2e7d28
10-28 16:28:35.491 D/CameraPreview( 2405): pause()
```

Comment: If I downgrade to

implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'

then work fine on Android 6 and Android 9.0

Comment: this

    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'
    // Attention: Not upgrade to 3.3.0+ for backward compatibility with Androd 6.0 and below
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
also work on Android 6.0 and Android 9.0
Nice.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1170#issuecomment-494778246

> Tough call there. On the one hand I can't publish the Android app
> anymore, so it's kind of 'deprecated'. The core library can still be
> used outside Android, or in another Android app. That app would have
> to target API 24, yes. The app in the project can't target API 24, so
> it also doesn't quite make sense to leave it in a state where it won't
> run on API < 24. Another solution is to modify the Android app to
> depend on the 3.3.x core library and leave it there.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/1170#issuecomment-533527019

> Please read all of the messages above. You can a) use 3.3.x, or b)
> target API 24.